# Is it possible to weight paint with a deformation from edit mode?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature, bones

I have tried and tried and tried to weight paint from automatic weights and the like and I can't make the mesh deform the way I want it to for the life of me. It always seems like the character's knees in my model clip through the skirt. The skirt never seems to move far enough like there isn't enough strength from the weight paint. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make the mesh deform a certain way based on the view in edit mode. Like say I rotate the thigh bone about 30 degrees and then go into edit mode and deform the mesh the way I want it to and then have the weight paint deform the mesh exactly as it appears in edit mode. And of course if the bone is back to its regular position the mesh would look normal again. Is this possible?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pressing 'Normalize All' when in weight paint mode appears to have resolved my issue. the mesh of the skirt now seems to move far enough to avoid clipping issues

Comment: Make sure you are in vertex select mode when you normalize - and that all vertexes are selected